# Retrieve value by customComboBoxItem

Tags: c#

I'm trying to retrieve data of dr.GetInt32(0) and assign it into the combobox selectedvalue but I Get this error.

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'WindowsFormsApplication2.customComboBoxItem.customComboBoxItem(string,
>   string)' has some invalid
>   arguments c:\users\bilgisayar\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Form1.cs  56  36  WindowsFormsApplication2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    class customComboBoxItem
    {
        private string text;
        private string value;

        public customComboBoxItem(string strText, string strValue)
        {
            this.text = strText;
            this.value = strValue;
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get { return value; }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<customComboBoxItem> customItem = new List<customComboBoxItem>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.DataSource = customItem;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
        }

        string path;

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=randomcompany;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            temizle();
        }

        void temizle()
        {

            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button4.Enabled = false;

            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeID,EmployeeFirstName,EmployeeLastName FROM Employees", cnn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    customItem.Add(new customComboBoxItem(dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2), dr.GetInt32(0)));
                }
            }

            cnn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `string` value to the `customComboBoxItem` constructor. `dr.GetInt32(0)` returns `int` value, so you should cast it to `string`.

```
customItem.Add(new customComboBoxItem(dr.GetString(1) + dr.GetString(2), dr.GetInt32(0).ToString()));
```